# What is the difference between sudo and sudo -H?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

Sometimes I see in many websites' tutorials the use of `sudo -H + command` for example `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. However I know that `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` can do the work.
So anyone please can tell me what is the difference between `sudo -H` and `sudo`?

Comment: See [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference comes when e.g. `gedit` writes a preference file or something similar to `$HOME` when it is closed. Many programs do that.

When you run

```
sudo gedit ...
```

then `$HOME` is still set to *your* home directory (say `/home/singrium`) and `gedit` will write its settings there but the preferences file will then be owned by `root`. This might make it difficult to run `gedit` as your user afterwards because then `gedit` cannot write its settings due to a lack of permissions.

When you instead run

```
sudo -H gedit ...
```

then `$HOME` will be set to `root`'s home directory (usually `/root`) and `gedit` will write its preferences file there without affecting your account.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo -H` is the same as `sudo --set-home`

> -H, --set-home
>                    Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
>                    variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
>                    password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may
>                    be the default behavior.

It avoids the user's home folder permissions to be changed to root.

Answer (score 1):

From `man sudo`

`-H' The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by default) as specified by the password database. Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.`

`-H gedit` in your case will set the `$HOME` variable to point to `root` (by default) instead of being your user home dir.